# Subquery returned more than 1 row

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

I have a line of code that should have an output of dates but it says on my SQL report:

> subquery returned more than 1 row

Here is my code:

```
try 
{
    String contract = "UPDATE vsl375 SET "
    + "contract = (SELECT disdate FROM embarkationdetails "
    + "WHERE vsl375.crewid = embarkationdetails.CrewId)";

    pst = conn.prepareStatement(contract);
    pst.execute();

} 
catch (SQLException e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);}
```

I want my output to be like this:

```
ID_Number
---------
1
2
3

DATE
----
01/25/2016
01/25/2016
01/26/2016
```

Comment: Are you sure your query is proper? It will update all the entries of the vs1375 table.

Comment: yes that is I want to do with the table

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySql, PostgreSQL, ...? This is important to know because each product has its own implementation of SQL that can differ wildly from other products.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery you have in `UPDATE` doesn't work this way - it is supposed to only return one value, and that single value is then written in every target row (in you case, all rows). It is *not* evaluated for each target row.

Depending on the DB type you're using, you could use `UPDATE ... FROM` (note that this is not a standard SQL syntax) or `MERGE` to do what you need.

```
MERGE INTO vsl375 tgt
  USING embarkationdetails src
  ON (tgt.crewid = src.CrewId)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET contract = src.disdate;
```